# Display Object Data Returned From Backend

Tags: angular

I am receiving object data in the format:

```
import { Istock } from './istock'
import { Dateclose } from './dateclose'

export class Cagr {
    buySell: Istock;
    firstReturn: number;
    sell: Dateclose;
    buy : Dateclose; 
}
```

This is the istock.ts file:

```
export class Istock {
date: Date;
close: number;
buysell: string;
}
```

This is the dateclose.ts file:

```
export class Dateclose {
date: Date;
close: number;
```

}

This is the format I get from the server printed in the console log window:

```
buy: {date: "2019-01-02T00:00:00", close: 156.6423}
buySell: Array(6)
0: {date: "2015-06-02T00:00:00", close: 121.2015, buySell: "Sell"}
1: {date: "2015-06-03T00:00:00", close: 121.3507, buySell: "Sell"}
2: {date: "2015-11-11T00:00:00", close: 109.2406, buySell: "Sell"}
3: {date: "2016-01-22T00:00:00", close: 95.4197, buySell: "Buy"}
4: {date: "2016-01-25T00:00:00", close: 93.5569, buySell: "Buy"}
5: {date: "2016-04-08T00:00:00", close: 102.7861, buySell: "Sell"}
firstReturn: 1.0783205505422155
sell:
    close: 199.9002
    date: "2019-04-30T00:00:00"
```

This is the html file in attempting to print the values to the browser page:

```
<div>
            <mat-list >
                <mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of stockdata ">
                  {{item.buysell.date | date}} {{item.buysell.close | currency}} {{item.buySell.buysell | json}} {{item.firstReturn | json}}
                </mat-list-item>
            </mat-list>
  </div>
```

I get this error:

```
cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

This is the corresponding component file :

```
export class DemostockComponent {

 stock: String;
stockdata
public buySellData$: Observable<Cagr[]>

constructor(private api: DemoapiService){}

getStock() {
  this.buySellData$ = this.api.getStock();
  this.buySellData$.subscribe(
           // Use the `data` variable to produce output for the user
           data => {
             this.stockdata = data;
             console.log("data from backend this.stockdata, this.stockdata", this.stockdata);
           }
         )}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the server is not returning what you expect it to return. According to your output, you might want to change:

```
*ngFor="let item of stockdata"
```

to:

```
*ngFor="let item of stockdata.buySell"
```

Then you would just use `{{item.date | date}} ...` in your template. **Note that this does not match the data structure which you have posted**. It should rather look like this:

```
export class Cagr {
    buySell: Istock[];
    firstReturn: number;
    sell: Dateclose;
    buy : Dateclose; 
}
```

I hope that helps!